# XCeed DataGrid for WPF v4.x: How to create multiple column headers

Tags: wpf, xceed-datagrid, xceed

Is there any way to create multiple column headers in ***XCeed DataGrid for WPF v4.x***?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this.

Comment: Then we should ask XCeed folks for this feature in upcoming 4.x release :)